# Почему не входит в аккаунт с сессией? PHP , MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

почему не входит в аккаунт с сессией? Не открывается **index.php**?
Вы пишите если что, я скину вам нужные фотографии, заранее спасибо за помощь <3

**Сессия вроде открыта... не понимаю в чём проблема.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP7Sm.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Регистрация работает нормально

Comment: Из ваших скринов можно увидеть, что после введенных данных, пользователя перебрасывает в index.php. И что значит не входит в аккаунт с сессией? Какие ошибки выдает? Если вы сохраняете данные пользователя в сессии, то и должны выводить их из сессии в где-нибудь в html на другой странице. (в том же index.php хотя бы)

Comment: Я бы вывел всё в index.php, но он просто не переходит на этот index.. не перебрасывает

Comment: не переходит, потому что перед перенаправлением выводится какой-то текст, а header можно отправить ДО вывода любого текста. За вывод кода картинкой, а не текстом, можно минусов в вопрос насобирать. Исправляйте